# How to execute named code blocks written in any language using a shell script?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, command-line-arguments

## History

---

Recently,  I cobbled together a shell script that can execute a named code block from inside an org-mode file using the command-line.

I copied source code directly from the [org-mode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Batch-execution.html#Batch-execution) and the `org-babel-open-src-block-result` function in `ob-core.el`.

At the moment, the shell script **only *works* with elisp code blocks**.

```sh
  # Shell Command
  ./call-named-code-block-examples.sh ./call-named-code-block-examples.org "get-org-version" 2>/dev/null
  # Returns Expected Results
  # org-mode version: 9.0
```

The script **displays an error** when calling code blocks written in other languages, e.g. ruby.

```sh
  # Shell Command
 ./call-named-code-block-examples.sh ./call-named-code-block-examples.org "get-emacs-version"
  # Returns Error Message
  # No org-babel-execute function for ruby!
```

---

## Question

---

How to execute named code blocks written in any language using a shell script?

> Below is the shell script and org-mode code needed to reproduce the issue:

---

### Shell Script

---

**Save as file named:** call-named-code-block-examples.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# -*- mode: shell-script -*-
#
# Call named code block in org-mode file
#
DIR=`pwd`
FILE=$1
CODE_BLOCK=$2

emacs -Q --batch \
  --eval "
(progn
  (require 'org)(require 'ob)(require 'ob-table)(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
  (mapc (lambda (file)
        (find-file (expand-file-name file \"$DIR\"))
        (let ((re-run (quote t))
          (results (quote \"ERROR: Did not call code block: $CODE_BLOCK\")))
    (save-excursion
      (org-babel-goto-named-src-block \"$CODE_BLOCK\")
      (let ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info 'light)))
        (when info
          (save-excursion
        ;; go to the results, if there aren't any then run the block
        (goto-char (or (and (not re-run) (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))
                   (progn (org-babel-execute-src-block)
                      (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))))
        (end-of-line 1)
        (while (looking-at \"[\n\r\t\f ]\") (forward-char 1))
        ;; open the results
        (if (looking-at org-bracket-link-regexp)
            ;; file results
            (org-open-at-point)
          (let ((r (org-babel-format-result
                (org-babel-read-result) (cdr (assq :sep (nth 2 info))))))
            (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create \"*Org-Babel Results*\"))
            (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
            (insert r)
            (setq results (buffer-string))))
        t)))
      t)
    (princ (format \"%s\" results))
    )

      (kill-buffer))
    '(\"$FILE\"))
  )
"
```

---

### Named Code Block Examples

---

**Save as file named:** call-named-code-block-examples.org

```
#+NAME: get-org-version
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp 
(format "org-mode version: %s" (org-version))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: get-org-version
: org-mode version: 9.0

#+NAME: get-emacs-version
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby  :var emacs_version=(format "Emacs Version: %s" (substring (version) 10 16))
  emacs_version
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: get-emacs-version
: Emacs Version: 24.5.1
```

Comment: I also like the question. I do have some handy pieces of code in my org files and maybe running them like this might turn out useful for me.

Comment: @RomanGrazhdan - Thanks for your help! One of my goals when I asked this question was to inspire others and to provide a glimpse about how org-mode might be integrated into other automation tools like Jenkins, Chef, BladeLogic and Puppet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In you `progn`, you do load org-babel, but **don't load any extra languages**:

http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html#configure

It does work in your regular Emacs session because these are obviously loaded somewhere in your init.el

So I've saved your script and edited it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*- mode: shell-script -*-
#
# Call named code block in org-mode file
#
DIR=`pwd`
FILE=$1
CODE_BLOCK=$2

emacs -Q --batch \
  --eval "
(progn
  (require 'org)(require 'ob)(require 'ob-table)(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
;; Don't forget to load languages
;; ------8<------------------
(org-babel-do-load-languages
   'org-babel-load-languages
   '((sh . t)
     (ruby . t)
     (emacs-lisp . t)
     ))
;; ------8<------------------
  (mapc (lambda (file)
        (find-file (expand-file-name file \"$DIR\"))
        (let ((re-run (quote t))
          (results (quote \"ERROR: Did not call code block: $CODE_BLOCK\")))
    (save-excursion
      (org-babel-goto-named-src-block \"$CODE_BLOCK\")
      (let ((info (org-babel-get-src-block-info 'light)))
        (when info
          (save-excursion
        ;; go to the results, if there aren't any then run the block
        (goto-char (or (and (not re-run) (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))
                   (progn (org-babel-execute-src-block)
                      (org-babel-where-is-src-block-result))))
        (end-of-line 1)
        (while (looking-at \"[\n\r\t\f ]\") (forward-char 1))
        ;; open the results
        (if (looking-at org-bracket-link-regexp)
            ;; file results
            (org-open-at-point)
          (let ((r (org-babel-format-result
                (org-babel-read-result) (cdr (assq :sep (nth 2 info))))))
            (pop-to-buffer (get-buffer-create \"*Org-Babel Results*\"))
            (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
            (insert r)
            (setq results (buffer-string))))
        t)))
      t)
    (princ (format \"%s\" results))
    )

      (kill-buffer))
    '(\"$FILE\"))
  )
"
```

I then created a test Org file:

```
#+NAME: test-ruby-block
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :results output
puts "HELLO"
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: test-ruby-block
: HELLO
```

And checked your script on it:

```
hoodoo@T450s [06:32:51 PM] [~/Org] [master *]
-> % bash org-babel-run.sh test-script.org test-ruby-block
Position saved to mark ring, go back with C-c &.
executing Ruby code block (test-ruby-block)...
Code block evaluation complete.
HELLO%
hoodoo@T450s [06:32:59 PM] [~/Org] [master *]
-> %
```

EDIT: Don't use this code as is, it's potentially dangerous:

```
hoodoo@T450s [06:32:59 PM] [~/Org] [master *]
-> % bash org-babel-run.sh test-script.org no-such-block
source-code block ‘no-such-block’ not found in this buffer
executing Ruby code block (test-ruby-block)...
Code block evaluation complete.
HELLO%
```

The code block is evaluated anyway, if you have unlink somewhere in your file it might result in a huge mess.

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thank you!

Comment: BTW I've noticed that if you mistype code block name it would execute it anyway. Not sure you really want this.